# Retrieve JSONarray and pass into a String array volley

Tags: php, android, arrays, json, android-volley

I need to retrieve a JSON array from a php script and put the values into TextView and Button items using volley, as far as I know the php script is working fine and returns a Json array like this (tested using POSTMAN) ;

```
 [{"ID":"5","CAT":"R","PREG":"E","RESP1":"o","RESP2":"ao","RESP3":"Fa","RESPC":"Oc","id":"4.306107120873506"}]
```

I have Internet permission and everything for volley set up in the manifest (as my POST request works fine) but I cant get it working, here is the method;

```
 private void retrieveQuestion() {

        JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, Constants.URL_RETRIEVE, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
                            JSONObject jObj = arr.getJSONObject(0);
                            textViewCategoria.setText(jObj.getString("CAT"));
                            textViewPregunta.setText(jObj.getString("PREG"));
                            buttonResp1.setText(jObj.getString("RESP1"));
                            buttonResp2.setText(jObj.getString("RESP2"));
                            buttonResp3.setText(jObj.getString("RESP3"));
                            buttonResp4.setText(jObj.getString("RESPC"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });

        RequestHandler.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);

    }
```

The retrieveQuestion() method  has to run when I click a button but it does nothing at all (the button works perfectly ofc) I dont know why... Im using a Singleton pattern with RequestQueue, I can post it, the php script or the entire Activity if needed but Im pretty sure the problem is in that method.

Comment: I couldnt get it working so I changed to StringRequest and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you want to update a UI element in your thread,

You have to use to  runOnUiThread func for update UI elements

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Update UI elements
          textViewCategoria.setText(jObj.getString("CAT"));

          textViewPregunta.setText(jObj.getString("PREG"));

          buttonResp1.setText(jObj.getString("RESP1"));

          buttonResp2.setText(jObj.getString("RESP2"));

          buttonResp3.setText(jObj.getString("RESP3"));

          buttonResp4.setText(jObj.getString("RESPC"));
        }
    });
```

Comment: As far as I've read I just need another thread when there are heavy processing operations set before the UI update and there are not in my activity, its just the PHP script execute and updating the UI elements.

Comment: Tasks that you run on a thread from a thread pool aren't running on your UI thread, they don't have access to UI objects. Use a Handler that's running on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can try bellow like..Json look like

```
{"ParentNode":[{"ID":"1","CAT":"R"}]}
```

Volley full method  bellow

```
 private void doLoginAction() {

    pDialog.show();
    String url_login = "http://era.com/test_sstem/public/login";


    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_login,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    //pDialog.dismiss();


                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray loginNodes = jsonObject.getJSONArray("ParentNode");
                        for (int i = 0; i < loginNodes.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jo = loginNodes.getJSONObject(i);
                            String ID = jo.getString("ID");
                            String CAT = jo.getString("CAT");



                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    try {

                        if (error instanceof TimeoutError ) {
                            //Time out error

                        }else if(error instanceof NoConnectionError){
                            //net work error

                        } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                            //error

                        } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                            //Erroor
                        } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                            //Error

                        } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                            //Error

                        }else{
                            //Error
                        }
                        //End


                    } catch (Exception e) {


                    }

                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("uname", "era@gmail.com");
            params.put("pass", "123456");



            return params;
        }

    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: I have not parent node tho, the JSON array looks like the one I posted, should I modify the PHP script to return a different one like yours?